# Jupyter Notebook nb_conda_kernel not able to find current environment

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, environment

Jupyter notebook is not opening kernels in my current environment. Running `which jupyter` in command line indicates the proper directory within the environment, my environment has nb_conda installed using conda_forge and also has ipykernel installed, I just updated conda to version 4.5.12. When I open jupyter notebook I am able to see a conda tab and my current environment shows up there but when I try to create a new notebook or change kernel within a notebook my current environment does not show up. When I run `jupyter notebook` in iterm (I am using zsh) I receive a message `[nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 2 kernels found` which is a problem because I have three kernels (root, an old environment, my current environment).

I've tried looking through different help forums on github and following the readme but I still haven't managed to get it to work. Any help would appreciated!

Comment: What do you get if you run `conda info -e` on your terminal?

Comment: `$ conda info -e`\\
`# conda environments:`\\
`#`\\
`base                     /Users/japjot/anaconda3`\\
`oldenv                  /Users/japjot/anaconda3/envs/oldenv`\\
`currentenv                  *  /Users/japjot/anaconda3/envs/currentenv`

Note: I am using \\ to indicate line seperations

Comment: In the `currentenv`, try `conda upgrade ipykernel`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?